# Does Bundler have to be installed so that singularity.gs can be installed?

Tags: singularitygs

do you have to have Bundler installed to install singularity.gs or can you install like on the video on Viemo?

Comment: Docs: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0):

While you don't need Bundler per se, it is highly recommended that if you are working in any Ruby stack that you use Bundler to ensure that your gem dependencies are locked in place and you don't run into incompatibility issues across gem updates or across team. When singularity 1.2.0 gets a full release, you'll be able to drop the Singularity Sass straight into your project and not need the gem, but if you are compiling with the Ruby compiler it's still recommended to use Bundler.

Comment: Thanks so much for info, I have bundler installed but im confused about creating a Gemfile?  If I run the bundle init it creates a Gemfile in my specified directory.  I'm not sure what a .gemspec is?  I know that I need to put : gem "sass", "~>3.2.0"
gem "compass", "~>0.12.0"
gem "singularitygs", "~>1.1.2"

Comment: Where do you see .gemspec anywhere? Add them to your Gemfile.

Comment: sorry for my confusing rookie question, I got bundeler installed and I think I was reading to much into bundler instruction.  I ran bundler init, and it created my gem file, i placed my dependencies in that gemfile, and ran bundler install singularitygs, and it created my project!  Where should my gemfile and gemfile.lock be place? IN the root directory of my project or somewhere else? is there a rule where the gemfile should be or must be? thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Put it next to your config.rb file

Comment: ok that clears stuff up, so each time I start a new project with singularity.gs, I I generate my gemfile, and then after creating my a new project place my gemfile in the root folder next to my config.rb file.  So each project I start has to have a gemfile generated in order for singularity work? right?

Comment: how do I get the @include background-grid; to work to see my grid in the background? I was hoping to see it so I could practice working with the different grids starting out.